# Approximating to the identity by polynomials (Terrance Tao Analysis 2 , 3rd ed , page-73, ex.3.8.2)

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, weierstrass-approximation

### Context

> (Approximation to the identity) Let $\epsilon >0$ and $0 < \delta <1$. A function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be an $(\epsilon, \delta)$- approximation to the identity if it obeys the following three properties:
>
> (1) $f$ is supported on $[-1, 1]$, and $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $-1 \le x \le 1$.
>
> (2) $f$ is continuous, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f =1$.
>
> (3) $|f(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $\delta \le |x| \le 1$.

### Question

> (a) Prove that for any real number $0 \le y \le 1$ and any natural number $n \ge 0$, that $(1-y)^n \ge 1-ny$.
>
> (b) Show that $\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n \ge \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$. (Hint: for $|x| \le 1/\sqrt{n}$, use part (a); for $|x| \ge 1/\sqrt{n}$, just use the fact that $(1-x^2)$ is positive. It is also possible to proceed via trigonometric substitution, but I would not recommend this unless you know what you are doing.)
>
> (c) Prove Lemma 3.8.8:  For every $\epsilon >0$ and $0 < \delta <1$ there exists an $(\epsilon, \delta)$- approximation to the identity which is a polynomial $P$ on $[-1, 1]$ .
>
> (Hint: choose $f(x)$ to equal $c(1-x^2)^N$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$ and to equal zero for $x \not\in [-1, 1]$, where $N$ is a large number $N$, where $c$ is chosen so that $f$ has integral $1$, and use (b).) .

### Attempt

a. Done using induction.

b. as suggested in the hint,
$$\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n = \int_{-1/\sqrt{n}}^{1/\sqrt{n}} (1-x^2)^n +\int_{-1}^{-1/\sqrt{n}} (1-x^2)^n+\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^1 (1-x^2)^n.$$

I get $\int_{-1/\sqrt{n}}^{1/\sqrt{n}} f\ge \frac4{3\sqrt{n}}$. But, I am not sure how to compute the second and third term. How can I use the fact that $(1-x^2)$ is positive?

c.  I understand that $f$ satisfies (1). But, I think $c$ must depends on $N$ to make the integral 1. Doesn't it? Then, does it still satisfy property (2)? I am also not sure about property (3). How the result in (b) helps to show (3)?

I appreciate if you give some help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423383/why-does-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn1-x2n-0-if-0x-leq-1?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022167/proving-a-sequence-of-functions-is-an-approximation-to-the-identity?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b) you only need the fact that the second and third terms are  $\geq 0$. So $\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{n}dx \geq \frac  4 {3\sqrt n} \geq \frac 1 {\sqrt n}$.
For (c) we choose $c$ so that $c\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{N}dx =1$. By (b) this gives $c \leq \sqrt N$. For $\delta \leq |x|\leq 1$ we get $|f(x)| \leq \sqrt N (1-\delta^{2})^{N}$. Can you show that $\sqrt N t^{N} \to 0$ as $ N \to \infty$ for any $t \in (0,1)$? Once you show this we can choose $N$ large enough to make $f$ an $(\epsilon, \delta)$ approximation to the identity.