# Follow up on approximating identity by polynomials (Terence Tao Analysis 2, 3rd ed , pg-73, ex .3.8.2)

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3596811/688539). I'll quote it here in case anything happens to it:

> For (b) you only need the fact that the second and third terms are  $\geq 0$. So $\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{n}dx \geq \frac  4 {3\sqrt n} \geq \frac 1 {\sqrt n}$.
> For (c) we choose $c$ so that $c\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{N}dx =1$. By (b) this gives $c \leq \sqrt N$. For $\delta \leq |x|\leq 1$ we get $|f(x)| \leq \sqrt N (1-\delta^{2})^{N}$. Can you show that $\sqrt N t^{N} \to 0$ as $ N \to \infty$ for any $t \in (0,1)$? Once you show this we can choose $N$ large enough to make $f$ an approximate identity.

Here are my doubts on the above answer:

1. To my understanding, we wanted to show that $f(x)$ is approximation to identity, but, here it seems that we are changing function. The choice of $\epsilon$ and $\delta $ bound are related to $N$. So, are we proving the property for a family of function rather than a particular function in itself? Hopefully I make sense here..
2. How do we show that $N$ is 'choosable' such that for a given $(\epsilon,\delta)$, the below equation is true?

$\sqrt{N}(1- \delta^2)^N < \epsilon$

More specifically, shouldn't we show that the above equation it self is solvable for $N$ somehow?

3. Why is it that $\sqrt{N}t^N \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ means that $f$ is an approximation to the identity identity?

Excuse me if these are very noob questions. I am a total beginner at these kind of proof problem in Analysis, and I need some help getting off the ground.

Comment: It was not written anywhere in that answer that $\epsilon =\sqrt N (1-\delta^{2})^N$ What is true is we can choose $N$ large enough so that $\sqrt N (1-\delta^{2})^N<\epsilon$ which gives $|f(x)| <\epsilon$.

Comment: I thought more and edited the question. @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite for first one- the choice of $N$ is related to $\epsilon,\delta$ (the other way round from what you said: $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are *fixed*). You could say it is for a family, since the proof gives many different $(\epsilon,\delta)$-approximations of the identity, one for each sufficiently large $N$.

For the second/third. If you expand the definition of a limit tending to zero, you should very quickly see it implies the existence of $N$ such that it is as small as you like (in this case $\epsilon$). But you could try to find an explicit $N$ by finding a weaker upper bound that is also smaller than $\epsilon$, but is explicitly solvable. Since $x<e^x$ we have $ 0< -\log(1-\delta^2)  \sqrt N < (1-\delta^2)^{-\sqrt N}$ which implies for $N>4$ that $$ 
\sqrt N (1-\delta^2)^N \le (1-\delta^2)^{N-\sqrt N}\log\frac1{1-\delta^2} \le  (1-\delta^2)^{\sqrt N}\log\frac1{1-\delta^2}.$$
And now it suffices to force
$$ (1-\delta^2)^{\sqrt N}\log\frac1{1-\delta^2} < \epsilon \iff N>\left(\frac1{\log\frac1{1-\delta^2}}\log\frac{\log\frac{1}{1-\delta^2}}{\epsilon}\right)^2.$$
The right hand side is some mess depending only on $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, so of course such $N$ exists, e.g. $$N=\max\left(5,\left\lceil\frac1{\log\frac1{1-\delta^2}}\log\frac{\log\frac{1}{1-\delta^2}}{\epsilon}\right\rceil^2+1\right).$$

The limit argument is faster and cleaner if you don’t need to know any quantitative dependence. (e.g. The explicit bound shows that if $\delta$ was fixed then $N$ can  be chosen as something like $1+(\log\frac1\epsilon)^2$ times a constant.)

Comment: Hi Calvin, the first part is very clear. I'm trying to still understand what is going on in the second part.

Comment: @Buraian (A) Expanding on the limit argument - We have a horrible function ($f(N)=\sqrt N e^{-cN}$) that we want to show is less than e.g. $\epsilon$ for a large enough $N$.  The definition of $a_n\to 0$ is $$ \forall\epsilon>0 \exists N_0 \ \text{s.t.} \ \forall N>N_0: |a_n|<\epsilon$$
so $a_n\to 0$ implies a stronger result: for **all** $N>N_0(\epsilon)$ large enough, $a_n<\epsilon$ (as $a_n>0$). (cont)

Comment: (B) let me try a simpler example to explain the explicit bound. Let's pretend that we managed to show $f(N) ≤ 1/N$ for all $N>10$. Then it would be trivial to find $N$ such that $f(N)<\epsilon$: just take any $N>1/\epsilon$, e.g. $N=\lceil 1/\epsilon \rceil+1$. Then $1/N<\epsilon$, and therefore $$ f(N)<1/N < \epsilon$$ QED. Instead of $1/N$, I proved some exponential-type bound that is ugly, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Ok, so actually the issue here is that we only want to compare things rather than show the exact

Comment: Indeed, you would have to work a lot harder to find the "best possible" value of $N$.