# Prove $\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n \, dx \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

$$\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n \, dx\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

So, there is a same question about that. Here is the link; [Approximating to the identity by polynomials (Terrance Tao Analysis 2 , 3rd ed , page-73, ex.3.8.2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596780/approximating-to-the-identity-by-polynomials-terrance-tao-analysis-2-3rd-ed)

In that question, integral is separated from different points. Author says that one part of it is greater than $$\frac{4}{3 \, \sqrt{n}}.$$

How one can prove that?

Comment: $$\int_{ - 1/\sqrt n }^{1/\sqrt n } {(1 - x^2 )^n dx}  = 2\int_0^{1/\sqrt n } {(1 - x^2 )^n dx}  \ge 2\int_0^{1/\sqrt n } {(1 - n x^2 )dx} \mathop  = \limits^{t = \sqrt n x} 2\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}\int_0^1 {(1 - t^2 )dt}  = \frac{4}{{3\sqrt n }}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral appears in the normalization of the Legendre Polynomials. $n$ is assumed to be a natural number. Here is the computation. First we make the change of variables $x = cos(t)$ and use pithagorean identity to get:

$$ I = \int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^ndx = \int_{\pi}^0[\sin^2(t)]^n (-\sin t)dt = -\int_{\pi}^0\sin^{2n+1}(t) dt $$

Now we integrate by parts $n$ times, noting that the square bracket vanishes at both limits each time, getting:
$$I = - \frac{2n}{2n+1} \frac{2n-2}{2n-1} \frac{2n-4}{2n-3} ... \frac{2}{3} \int_{\pi}^0\sin(t) dt = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} · 2 $$
Now we can express the result in terms of factorials insetead of double factorials using:

$$ (2n)!! = 2^n n! $$
$$ (2n+1)!! = \frac{(2n + 1)!}{n! 2^n} $$

We finally get:

$$ I = \frac{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} $$

Hope this helps seeing if it's bigger or smaller than that.